# Changing map string keys and values to int keys and values

Tags: kotlin

I have two lists `teachers` and `students` and I have a map `teachers_to_students`.
The keys and the values of the map are both strings.
I want to transform it in the following manner: each key is replaced with the index of the teacher in the `teachers` list; each element of the value (it's a list) is replaced with the index of the student in the `students` list.

*My attempt:*

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val teachers_l = listOf("teacher1","teacher2","teacher3")
    val students_l = listOf("student1", "student2", "student3", "student4")

    val teachers_to_students = mapOf("teacher2" to listOf("student3"), "teacher1" to listOf("student1","student2"),  "teacher3" to listOf("student4"))

    val teachers_to_students_by_indices = mutableMapOf<Int,List<Int>>()

    for ((teacher,students) in teachers_to_students){
        val teacher_index = teachers_l.indexOf(teacher)

        val students_indices = mutableListOf<Int>()
        for (student in students){
            students_indices.add(students_l.indexOf(student))
        }
        teachers_to_students_by_indices[teacher_index] = students_indices 
    }
    print(teachers_to_students_by_indices)
}
```

Is there a more concise way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: also check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` operation has O(N) compexity. It's inside a loop, so that's already O(N^2).

It's better to build indexes in advance, so that each look-up will cost only O(1):

```kotlin
val teachers_index = teachers_l.withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
val students_index = students_l.withIndex().associate { it.value to it.index }
```

Now, all transformation could be done with:

```
val teachers_to_students_by_indices = teachers_to_students.asIterable().associate { (teacher, students) ->
    teachers_index[teacher] to students.map { students_index[it] }
}
```

Comment: Good point regarding the performance. I would simplify this code a little bit and use `map` instead of `asIterable().associate`

Comment: In this case you would get `List` of `Pair`s, not `Map`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Another thing I've been thinking about is how to avoid nullability in the resulting type because currently, the result is `Map<Int?, List<Int?>>`

Comment: If it's guaranteed, that all keys are present in respectful indices, the easiest way would be usage of not-null assertion operator (`teachers_index[teacher]!!`) . Otherwise, the one should use `getOrElse`/`getOrDefault` methods instead of simple indexed access operator (`teachers_index.getOrDefault(teacher, -1)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
val teachers_to_students_by_indices = teachers_to_students.entries.associate { (key, value) ->
    val keyIndex = teachers_l.indexOf(key)
    val valueIndices =  value.map { students_l.indexOf(it) }
    keyIndex to valueIndices
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.